# Handling click event using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, performance, click

I am trying to run a function when clicking an image(which is a game card,in my case), but it doesn't work.

That's what I did:

```
function setPlayerCards(cards)
{
    for(var i=0 ; i <cards.length ; i++)
    {
        var cardID = createCardID(cards[i]);
        var imagePath = createCardImagePath(cards[i]);

        $('<img class="card id="'+cardID +'" src=' + imagePath + '>').appendTo($("#playerCards"));
        $("#" + cardID ).click(function()
        {
            console.log(cardID  + "  clicked");//Just wrote it for debugging
            cardFromHandHBoxPressed(cards[i]);
        });
    }
}
```

The elements are created successfully and I can see the cards images, but nothing happens when I click them.

I have tried also other ways to run the function after a click.. but nothing works for me..

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: post a `jsfiddle` link showing your (non)working code in action

Answer (score 2):

The reason for not working is, you are missing `"` in your dynamically created tag

```
$('<img class="card" id="'+cardID +'" src=' + imagePath + '>').appendTo($("#playerCards"));
//.................^....................
```

Even it's not working then use [`event delegation`](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) method , since the buttons are created dynamically

```
$("#playerCards").on('click',"#" + cardID,function()
{
    console.log(cardID  + "  clicked");//Just wrote it for debugging
    cardFromHandHBoxPressed(cards[i]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
I have changed the " that was missing..

Anyway,I see the event delegation is used for all the children of the element.. 
However, I want to run the function "cardFromHandHBoxPressed(x)" with a different parameter for each one of my cards..

So I have tried my original solution, but now its seems that not all of the cards are clickable..